# Ajax post multiple variables via loop?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to post multiple variables from the already dynamically create-able "username" id's such as "username1", "username2", etc. I'm looking for a way to dynamically send these into **ONE** ajax post request. My problem is mainly with the `data` parameter.

```
  var numOfInputs = $('input').length;

  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "ajax.php",
     // need way to dynamically pass more of these via numOfInputs.
     data: ({username1 : $('#username1').val()}),
     success: function(msg){
       $('#statuses').html(msg);
     }
   });
```

requested html:

```
<input type="text" id="username1"></input><button id="add">+</button><button id="check">Check</button>

<div id="added-fields">
</div>

<div id="statuses">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = {};
for (var i = 1; i <= numOfInputs; i++) {
   data["username" + i] = $("#username" + i).val();
}
$.ajax(
   ...
   data: data,
   ....
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can say:

```
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "ajax.php",
     data: $('input').map(function() {
                          var o = {};
                          o[this.id] = this.value;
                          return o;
            });
   ...
```

Comment: Throws an error in console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in the map function wouldn't the key word "this" refer to the global object? Shouldn't the map function be written as function(v, i){ return { v.id: v.value; } }

Comment: @fsong: `this` would refer to current element being iterated over. You cannot have `v.id : v.value` as the key cannot be dynamic. so this is legal `"id": v.value"` but then, that is not waht the OP wanted.

Comment: Hmm.. according to [the api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), `this` in the map function is the global object. I will go and test this. You're absolutely right about the not being able to have dynamic key part though.